# Understanding the proof technique of $A\cup (B\cap C)\subseteq (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I used to learn it in a different way; 
\begin{align}
x\in A\cup (B\cap C)&\implies x\in A \textrm{ or } (x\in B \textrm{ and } x\in C)\tag{1}\\
&\implies (x\in A \textrm{ or } x\in B) \textrm{ and } (x\in A \textrm{ or } x\in C)\tag{2}\\
&\implies x\in (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)\tag{3}
\end{align}
using the different rules.

This <[link](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/347.summer14/settheory-proofs.pdf)> on page 2 has shown another way which questioned me a lot but I will try to make short questions.

It starts to assume that $x\in A\cup (B\cap C)$, that is, assuming with two cases, $x\in A$ and $x\in B\cap C$. The first case seems no problem to me when knowing about [or-introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction). But the last case doesn't really make sense to me. For example, if $x\in B\cap C$ then it means that $x$ is both in $B$ and $C$, so how can $x$ be in $A\cup B$ while ignoring the set $C$? I mean, where is the set $C$ if $x$ is in $A\cup B$? The same way, where the set $B$ is if $x\in A\cap C$.

How exactly is this proof technique structured? The proof above shows clearly what happens from $(1)$ to $(2)$, and from $(2)$ to $(3)$. This is the only thing that makes sense to me. But not like this link. It doesn't look like how it is implied but I feel like it's just checking if it's verified or that it only looks at the right side to make the left side imply.

Comment: $x\in A\cup(B\cap C)$ means $x\in A$ **or** $x\in B\cap C$. I'm guessing you meant the **or** there, correct?

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow I understand what it means. I used "and" to the cases. Should I write "or" instead?

Comment: I am referring the first sentence of your paragraph starting, "It starts to assume ..."

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow What I meant is that it shows the cases (i) $x\in A$, (ii) $x\in B\cap C$. Is it wrong to say "and" between the cases while knowing that it's not $x\in A\cap (B\cap C)$ I am talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It starts to assume that $x∈A∪(B∩C)$ , that is, assuming with two cases, $x∈A$  and $x∈B∩C$ . The first case seems no problem to me when knowing about or-introduction. But the last case doesn't really make sense to me. For example, if $x∈B∩C$  then it means that $x$  is both in $B$  and $C$ , so how can $x$  be in $A∪B$  while ignoring the set $C$ ? I mean, where is the set $C$  if $x$  is in $A∪B$ ? The same way, where the set $B$  is if $x∈A∩C$ .

It's not ignored, it's just examined in parallel.   If you can start with premise $Z$, then prove $X$ by one path, and in parallel prove $Y$ by another, then you have proven the conjunction $X\wedge Y$.   (If $Z\vdash X$ and $Z\vdash Y$, then $Z\vdash X\wedge Y\;$.)

$$
\cfrac{
 \cfrac{
  \cfrac{
   \cfrac{
    \cfrac{
     \cfrac{
      x\in B\cap C
     }{x\in B \wedge x\in C}
    }{x\in B}
   }{x\in A\vee x\in B}
  }{x\in A\cup B}
  \quad
  \cfrac{
   \cfrac{
    \cfrac{
     \cfrac{
      x\in B\cap C
     }{x\in B \wedge x\in C}
    }{x\in C}
   }{x\in A\vee x\in C}
  }{x\in A\cup C}
 }{x\in A\cup B \wedge x\in A\cup C}
}{x\in (A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)}
$$

Answer (score 2):

It uses the [Implies-subset relation](http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Implies_and_subset_relation) which states that (by definition)

> $$[A\subseteq B]\iff\forall x[x\in A\implies x\in B]$$

In addition we have:

> $$[x\in A\cap B]\iff[x\in A\wedge x\in B]$$

($\wedge$ means "and") and

> $$[x\in A\cup B]\iff[x\in A\vee x\in B]$$

and of course, $\vee$ means "or" (which is $x\in A$, $x\in B$ or both)

Answer (score 1):

The last step (i.e., the "second case") makes sense, but it could be worded more clearly. To keep it firmly in mind, here it is:

> In the second case (i.e., the case "$x\in B$ and $x\in C$"), we have $x\in A\cup B$ and $x\in A\cup C$, by the definition of a union. As before, by the definition of an intersection, it follows that $x\in (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$.

Okay, let's dissect this and see how it makes sense. First, the author begins the proof with "Let $x\in A\cup (B\cap C)$." Since the **second case** is all about what happens when $x\in B\cap C$, you clearly have that $x\in A\cup B$ *and* $x\in A\cup C$ by the definition of a union (the size of $A$ and whether or not its elements intersect with those of $B$ and $C$ does not matter since you are considering the *union*). What you need, namely $x\in(A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$, simply follows from this observation.

> If $x\in B\cap C$ then it means that $x$ is both in $B$ and $C$, so how can $x$ be in $A\cup B$ while ignoring the set $C$?

You are **not** ignoring the set $C$--you are simply stating that $x$ is in both $A\cup B$ **and** $A\cup C$ (<-- $C$ is not being ignored there). Does that make sense?

---

For what it's worth, the way you structured your own proof is *much* cleaner and elegant in my opinion. I would have done likewise. The proof in the PDF is verbose and convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x \in A \cup (B \cap C)$.
We have two cases here:
$$x \in A \;\mathrm{or}\; x \in B \cap C$$

You already know the case where $x \in A$ so I will leave that.
Let's assume that $x \in B \cap C$. So, we have $$x \in B \; \mathrm{and} \; x \in C$$

So, $$x \in B \subseteq A \cup B$$
and also
$$x \in C \subseteq A \cup C$$
Hence, $$x \in (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$$